# How can I stack sorted columns on mobile without gaps on desktop?

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem regarding the following layouts

```css
    .box1 {
        background: green;
        height: 80px;
    }

    .box2 {
        background: red;
        height: 270px;
    }

    .box3 {
        background: blue;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .box4 {
        background: yellow;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Layout 1</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 box1">box1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box2">box2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 box3">box3</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box4">box4</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <h1>Layout 2</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="box1">box1</div>
                <div class="box3">box3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="box2">box2</div>
                <div class="box4">box4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*Both are correct in some way and wrong in others*

**Layout 1** stacks the columns in the correct order (box1,2,3,4) on mobile screens,
but on desktop screens there are undesired gaps between the content due to different content sizes. This is the current layout I am working with.

**Layout 2** does not show the gaps of layout 1, but the columns do not stack correctly (box1,3,2,4).

I understand why both layouts behave the way they do.

**How can you create a layout that combines the desired results of both layouts using bootstrap or plain css?** (note that the project I am working on uses an older version of bootstrap).

Thanks

### Edit

The box heights can vary from page to page. I have just set them in a way that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Have you implemented any [flex features](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)? Seems they'd solve your problem.

Comment: @isherwood Would this really solve the problem regarding layout 1? I would still have the gaps due to stacking multiple rows right? Feel free to modify my code :)

Comment: I won't have time to investigate now. My suggestion was that you give it a try. You'll get a lot closer than you are now, and then you'd have a more specific question to ask.

Comment: Links you set are from BS 3.4, and in tags you set BS 4, which are you using ? Because `row` class for example do not act the same way

Comment: @MaxiGui Thanks for editing the question. Yes, as I mentioned the project still uses 3. Changed the Tag to bootstrap-3, could only find twitter-bootsrap-3 which is why I initially went with bs4 tag

Answer (score 0):

It is dirty but I managed it this way:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .layout-1 .box3{
    margin-top: -190px;
  }
  .layout-1 .box4{
    float:right;
  }
}
```

I am still searching for something nicer.

### DEMO

```css
.box1 {
    background: green;
    height: 80px;
}

.box2 {
    background: red;
    height: 270px;
}

.box3 {
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
}

.box4 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}

/*** ADDED ***/
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .layout-3 .row:first-child{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .layout-3 .box1{order:1;}
  .layout-3 .box2{order:2;}
  .layout-3 .box3{order:3;}

  .layout-3 .box2{
    position: relative;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .layout-1 .box3{
    margin-top: -190px;
  }
  .layout-1 .box4{
    float:right;
  }
  
  
  .layout-3 .row{
    position: relative;
  }
  .layout-3 .box2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .layout-3 .box4{
    float:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Layout 1</h1>

    <div class="container layout-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 box1">box1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box2">box2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 box3">box3</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box4">box4</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <h1>Layout 2</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="box1">box1</div>
                <div class="box3">box3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="box2">box2</div>
                <div class="box4">box4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <h1>Layout 3</h1>

    <div class="container layout-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 box1">box1</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 box3">box3</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box2">box2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 box4">box4</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :) Using a media query is an interesting approach. Unfortunately the box heights may vary from page to page, this is where your solution breaks apart. I am not even sure if what I am seeking is possible without using js :-/

Comment: I might have a way with display but it means that you will need to do html like "mobile version"  and "larger version" will it be a problem ?

Comment: Do you mean having each side column on the dom twice and then toggling them into view in different places on viewport changes?

Comment: @Andy Yes This is what I meant. Otherwise, I tried a layout 3, it is another approch, but not 100% successful.